# Calculating definite integrals from a graph consisting of two lines and a semicircle

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

[image: The graph of g consists of two straight lines and a semicircle. Use it to evaluate each integral.]

I honestly don't know how to do this I tried everything.

Comment: In the future, please type the problem here, rather than linking to it. Also, please tell us *what* you tried. If you say you tried *everything*, perhaps we will take you at your word and conclude the problem cannot be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $\int_a^b g(x)\,dx$ as the net area under the curve $y=g(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$. For the first question you have $a=0$ and $b=10$. On that interval the graph of $y=g(x)$ is a straight line that drops from the point $\langle 0,20\rangle$ to the point $\langle 10,0\rangle$. The area under that ‘curve’ is just a triangle. What are the base and height of that triangle? What is its area? That area is $\int_0^{10}g(x)\,dx$.

For the second question you want $a=10$ and $b=30$. You’re supposed to assume that the graph on that interval is the lower half of a circle. What’s the radius of that semicircle? What’s the area between it and the $x$-axis? What’s the **net** area under the curve $y=g(x)$ on the interval from $x=10$ to $x=30$? Remember, the region is below the $x$-axis, and that does make a difference.

For the third question you have only to add your answers to the first two to get $\int_0^{30}g(x)\,dx$ and then add to that $\int_{30}^{35}g(x)\,dx$, which can be calculated just the way you calculate the first integral.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write functions for each of the pieces using your algebra skills, and then integrate those.

The first integral with $x$ limits from $0$ to $10$ is the equation of the line through the points $(0,20)$, and $(10,0)$.

The second integral with limits from $10$ to $30$ is the equation of the lower half of a circle centered at $(20,0)$, with radius $r=10$. This will be a negative value ([signed area](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aSigned_Area)). Your question does not indicate you actually want "areas", just integrals, and so I cannot tell you to change the sign here.

The third integral has limits from $0$ to $35$. This is the sum of the first two integrals, plus the integral of the equation of the straight line through the points $(30,0)$ and $(35,5)$, and you will want to integrate that piece over $x$ from $30$ to $35$.

You need to construct the equations for two straight lines. For the circle, you need to find that equation, solve it for $y$, and then take the lower half of that circle.

With these three equations, you should have no problem answering the three questions. Best of luck and feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: I got part a right but part b and c and not working out for me.

Comment: Find the equation for the circle. Solve it for y. This leads to part b. You could just take the cheap way out and compute half the area of a circle of radius $10$ by geometry formula, but that would not be calculus, and so you should compute the integral. Note that they should want the negative value, the curve is under the $x$ axis, and I saw your original post. It did not indicate any particular desire for "areas", just integrals.

Comment: You don't need to give formulas for the functions to do this problem: that is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Part1:

The area under the curve is defined by the integral below:

$$ \int_0^{10} g(x)dx $$

and can be easily obtained by using the Area of a triangle function

$$ \frac12bh $$

which in this case would equal to

$$ \frac1210*20 = 100$$

therefore:
$$ \int_0^{10} g(x)dx = 100 $$

Part2 is another integral that is defined by the Area of a circle such that:
$$ A = \pi r^2 $$

or since it is only a Half-Circle and since it is below the x-axis it has to be negative:

$$ A = \int_{10}^{30} g(x)dx = \pi \frac {r^2}2 = -50\pi  $$

Before we can complete the 3rd part of the question you have to find:

$$ \int_{30}^{35} g(x)dx $$

using the same concept as in part1, the following is also true here:
$$ \frac12bh $$

therefore:

$$ A = \int_{30}^{35} g(x)dx = \frac12 {5} * {5}  = 12.5 $$

Now you can add it all together to say that:

$$ A = \int_{0}^{35} g(x)dx = 112.5 - 50\pi$$

Hopefully that is correct I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now also...